# Is there a way to develop an Expo app on 32-bit Windows?

Tags: windows, react-native, command-line-interface, 32-bit, expo

I'm just getting into React Native with Expo. My main machine is a MacBook but I'm sorting out some problems with that so I'm also looking into doing coding on my Windows 10 notebook as a backup, which has 32-bit Windows.

I know the Expo IDE, XDE, requires 64-bit Windows but so far I can't seem to either confirm nor deny whether I can run Expo from the command-line without the IDE on 32-bit Windows.

Comment: I too have a same problem. Please update this thread when you have a solution

Comment: @CreativeManix: I think it might work using the command line but on my limited little system I didn't manage to get either the Android emulator from the official SDK or the one from Genymotion to install so I don't know. It also didn't work with my Android phone with USB cable, but that could be me lack of any clue how to set up the networking required. It did build my app and output the QR code though.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Run Expo from i-OS Collaborated Android Windows API Based Cloud Play Store If Required